# Top 10 based on last month showing 6 previous months

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I want to show a graph with income from different parties over the last 6 months, but based on the top income of 10 people only based on the last month.

So this can change each month as the top 10 people can change when they deposit more money, so the graph will show these 10 people's deposits of the last 6 months, based on the last month deposit only.

**I already used a LAG function and a RANK() OVER PARTITION function.**

Comment: Is this a homework question?  What did you try so far?  Show your work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Read this, first:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you'll need rank or lag functions.

You can simply use an IN statement:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.depositDate between StartRangeDate and EndRangeDate
AND t.ID in(select ID from(SELECT s.id,sum(s.depositAmount) as total
                           from YourTable s
                           where s.date between ThisMonthStart and ThisMonthEnd
                           group by s.id)
            order by total
            limit 10)
```

You can play with the first select to select what ever you want/add a group by and sum them or I don't know.

Comment: I have two additional questions then:
1. What is the ID that you select after the IN statement ?
2. Why would I take s.ID if I already have t.ID and I actually do not have a s.ID as it's the same as t.ID?
Thank you !!

Comment: @Naj because you first have to identify those who did the top 1p deposits only on the past month and then you need another query to choose them from the past 6 month. Its two different condition you can combine them.

Comment: Thank you very much sagi, I am going to try it today ! =D

Comment: Oh by the way, I included after:

order by total DESC

then it showed me the top 10. Thank you once more my friend!

Comment: Just one last question, if you want you can answer =D. When I do use DESC, I do not get the top 10, but a top 6. I have to use limit 22 to get a top 10. Would you know why ?

Comment: That sounds wierd, what are the results when using limit 10?

Comment: It works when I use limit 10 without DESC, but then it's not based on the clients who have the highest flow/deposit most money in the last month, I don't know what it bases it on. It just takes 10 people. When I use DESC, it takes the top ones indeed - but only the top 6... really weird

Comment: You did ORDER BY total DESC ? really wierd

Comment: Yes, ORDER BY total DESC. Maybe I can use RANK () OVER(PARTITION..)? I'm going to try some things then.

Comment: Nah, rank is not necessarily. Try select only the inner query(the one with the limit and tell me what it returns)

Comment: Sorry to take your time. I had excluded the sum() to try it out. But I put it back in now and it worked..Really sorry to bother you with it, but I didn't see it before :S. Thank you for all your help and effort. You're the best!